# Como añadir un valor usando key en un array existente

Tags: cakephp, foreach

Estoy intentando almacenar el tiempo acomulado, lo he intentado de esta manera pero me da error a la hora de almacenarlo. No se si el procedimiento que estoy siguiente es el correcto.

```
$proyectosActivos = $this->Proyectos->find()->where(['activo'=>'1'])->all();


    foreach ($proyectosActivos as $clave=>$proyecto){
        $this->loadModel('ProyectosCategoriasTareas');

        $tareas = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas->find()->where(['proyecto_id' => $proyecto->id])->all();
        $hestimadas = 0;
        $hrealizas = 0;
        foreach ($tareas as $tarea){
            $hestimadas = $hestimadas + $tarea->tiempo_estimado;
            $hrealizas = $hrealizas + $tarea->tiempo_acomulado;
        }

        $proyectosActivos[$clave]['totalEstimado'] = $hestimadas;
        $proyectosActivos[$clave]['totalCalculado'] = $hrealizas;

    }
```

En $proyectosActivos tengo los siguientes campos id, name , activo , completado y me gustaria añadir los dos campos que estoy calculando para cada proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que puedes modificar los elementos sería pasándolos por referencia. Pero esto no es conforme a lo que quieres realmente:

```
    $proyectosActivos[$clave]['totalEstimado'] = $hestimadas;
    $proyectosActivos[$clave]['totalCalculado'] = $hrealizas;
```

El código están dentro de este bucle:

```
foreach ($proyectosActivos as $clave=>$proyecto){
```

Por lo tanto, lo que correspondería sería poner esos datos dentro de cada `$proyecto`. Lo podrías hacer así (la diferencia es que dentro del bucle se pasa `$proyecto` por referencia poniendo delante de la variable `&`:

```
foreach ($proyectosActivos as $clave=>&$proyecto){
    $this->loadModel('ProyectosCategoriasTareas');

    $tareas = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas->find()->where(['proyecto_id' => $proyecto->id])->all();
    $hestimadas = 0;
    $hrealizas = 0;
    foreach ($tareas as $tarea){
        $hestimadas = $hestimadas + $tarea->tiempo_estimado;
        $hrealizas = $hrealizas + $tarea->tiempo_acomulado;
    }

    $proyectos['totalEstimado'] = $hestimadas;
    $proyectos['totalCalculado'] = $hrealizas;

}
```

Para más detalles sobre pasar por referencia, puedes consultar el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php).